# Azure WebJob FileTrigger Path 'D:\home\data\...' does not exist

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I've created a WebJob to read files from Azure Files when they are created.
When I run it locally it works but it doesn't when I publish the WebJob.

My Main() function is:

```
static void Main()
    {
        string connection = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=MYACCOUNTNAME;AccountKey=MYACCOUNTKEY";

        JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration(connection);

        var filesConfig = new FilesConfiguration();
        if (config.IsDevelopment)
        {
            config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
            filesConfig.RootPath = @"c:\temp\files";
        }

        config.UseFiles(filesConfig);

        var host = new JobHost(config);
        // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
```

The function to be triggered when the file is created is:

```
public void TriggerTest([FileTrigger(@"clients\{name}", "*.txt", WatcherChangeTypes.Created)] Stream file, string name, TextWriter log)
{
    log.WriteLine(name + " received!"); 
    // ...
}
```

And the error I get when the WebJob is published is:

```
[08/17/2016 00:15:31 > 4df213: ERR ] Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Path 'D:\home\data\clients' does not exist.
```

The ideia is to make the WebJob to trigger when new files are created in the "clients" folder of the Azure Files.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What should be the path of the clients folder ?

Comment: The clients folder is located in the root level of my Azure Storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your requirement, I tested it on my side, then I reproduced your issue.

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Path 'D:\home\data\clients' does not exist

When publish the WebJob, the FilesConfiguration.RootPath would be set to the “D:\HOME\DATA” directory when running in Azure Web App. You could refer to the source code:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/master/src/WebJobs.Extensions/Extensions/Files/Config/FilesConfiguration.cs

As the following tutorial has mentioned, FilesConfiguration.RootPath should be set to a valid directory.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/extensible-triggers-and-binders-with-azure-webjobs-sdk-1-1-0-alpha1
Please check and make sure that the specified directory is existed in the Web APP which hosts in your WebJob.

> Trigger when new files are created in the "clients" folder of the Azure Files via WebJob

As far as I know,  there has two triggers for Azure Storage:

- QueueTrigger - When an Azure Queue Message is enqueued.
- BlobTrigger – When an Azure Blob is uploaded.

The new WebJobs SDK provide a File trigger which could trigger functions based on File events. 
However, a file trigger could monitor file additions/changes to a particular directory, but there seems to be no trigger for monitor file additons/changes on Azure File Storage.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure Environment, the "Web-Jobs" are stored in its local folder where known as "**D:\home**" and "**D:\local**" is the local folder used by the Web-hooks. I was in need to use a folder for temporary usage of downloading a file from SFTP server and again read the file from that local temporary location file and consume it in my application.

I have used the "**D:\local\Temp**" as the temporary folder which is created by the code after checking the folder existence, then after creating the folder the code will download a file from server and store to this location and then read from the same location and delete the file from that temporary folder.