# How to get FileTrigger to work with Azure file storage in Webjob

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, azure-webjobs-triggered

I have a webjob that I have set up to be triggered when a file is added to a directory:

```
[FileTrigger(@"<DIR>\<dir>\{name}", "*", WatcherChangeTypes.Created, autoDelete: true)] Stream file,
```

I have it configured:

```
var config = new JobHostConfiguration
                {
                    JobActivator = new NinjectActivator(kernel)
                };
                var filesConfig = new FilesConfiguration();
#if DEBUG
                filesConfig.RootPath = @"C:\Temp\";
#endif
                config.UseFiles(filesConfig);
                config.UseCore();
```

The path is for working locally and I was expecting that commenting out the FilesConfiguration object leaving it default would allow it to pick up the connection string I have set up and trigger when files are added. This does not happen it turns out that by default the RootPath is set to "D:\Home" and produces an InvalidOperationException

```
System.InvalidOperationException : Path 'D:\home\data\<DIR>\<dir>' does not exist.
```

How do I get the trigger to point at the File storage area of the storage account I have set up for it. I have tried removing the FilesConfiguration completely from Program.cs in the hope that it would work against the settings but it only produces the same Exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> System.InvalidOperationException : Path 'D:\home\data\\' does not exist.

When you publish to azure, the [default directory](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/master/src/WebJobs.Extensions/Extensions/Files/Config/FilesConfiguration.cs) is `D:\HOME\DATA`, so when you run webjob it could not find the path so you get the error message.

> How do I get the trigger to point at the File storage area of the storage account I have set up for it.

The connectionstring you have set have two  applies: one is used for dashboard logging and the other is used for application functionality (queues, tables, blobs).

It seems that **you could not get filetrigger working with azure file storage**. 
So, if you want to invoke your filetrigger when you create new file, you could go to `D:\home\data\` in **KUDU** to create a `DIR` folder and then create new .txt file in it.

The output is as below:

[image]

BTW, it seems that you'd better not use `autoDelete` when you create file, if use you will get error like:

`NotSupportedException: Use of AutoDelete is not supported when using change type 'Changed'.`

Comment: Yes and this is exactly what I am doing but I was hoping I could get it to trigger from File storage. Will keep an eye on autodelete. Can I mount a directory in the D:\Data\Home hierarchy on my local machine?

Comment: And the FileTrigger here could [monitor file additions/changes to a particular directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986420/azure-webjob-filetrigger-path-d-home-data-does-not-exist), but there seems to be [no trigger for monitor file additons/changes on Azure File Storage](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/20324680-add-trigger-for-azure-file-storage).

Comment: Just to update on this I ended up going with a Blob and BlobTrigger to achieve what we needed.

Comment: Glad to see you have solve you problem. As I have said, you could use queue, blob trigger to achieve it.